# What's the best/most efficient way to flatten the values of an object?

Tags: javascript

I currently have an object that resembles the following:

```js
//object
{
    "Question 1": ["Answer 1"],
    "Question 2": ["Answer 2"],
    "Question 3": ["Answer 3"],
    //...
}
```

and I'd like to find the most efficient way to remove that inner array that contains each answer, ending up with this:

```js
//newObject
{
    "Question 1": "Answer 1",
    "Question 2": "Answer 2",
    "Question 3": "Answer 3",
    //...
}
```

There will almost always only be one item inside the inner array, but if there are multiple then them being comma-separated (as from .toString()) is fine.

So far, I've got the following:

```js
let newObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([question, [answer]]) => [question, answer]))
```

This seems to work fine but I'm not so sure about the efficiency of creating an object from an iteration of an array of an object.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Your code won't comma-separate multiple array elements\. It just gets the first element of the array and ignores the rest.

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate the response but it's not very helpful to somebody who is learning! I'd like to learn the best and most efficient ways of doing things, not merely what "works", potentially creating problems for myself (and others) later on!

Comment: If you're just learning you should focus on basic algorithms, not trivial issues like this.

Comment: I'm really trying to help you, by telling you that finding the "best" way to do this isn't important. It will practically never make a difference.

Comment: Content of the question aside, https://jsben.ch/ is a very handy tool for JS optimization issues. I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: @Joe this looks very useful indeed, thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a `forEach` over the keys and set the new values.

Taking only the first element:

```js
Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => { newObject[key] = object[key][0] });
```

Using the toString method:

```js
Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => { newObject[key] = object[key].toString() });
```

Comment: Thank you, Exalted Toast! This seems like a much better solution.